# Can I download the Windows 10 upgrade and install it later?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I understand that there's a notification that comes up on Windows 7 about installing Windows 10. What if I don't want to install it now, but want to download it now and install it maybe in a few months or a year or two? Is that possible?

Comment: You’ll have a free, full version of Windows 10 -- not a trial or a lite version -- if you complete your upgrade before July 29, 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Download the [media creating tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install)

Run the tool and you will be asked whether to "Upgrade PC now" or "Create installation media for another PC".

Choose "Create installation media for another PC" and select the language and windows version to download.

It will then ask you whether you want to create a bootable USB or download ISO.

If you have a spare USB flash drive then select the first option and specify the drive and it will download and install it on that drive.

Otherwise chose download ISO where you can store it in your PC and create a DVD from it once you decide To install the Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of. Basically MS isn't going to upgrade your older versions to newer versions *in perpetuity*. This isn't a freebie - its an attempt to get people on the latest version, and on the windows 10 tracks.

While you can create media *now* and upgrade later, there's a point where the licence activation for upgrades may not work. Its also unclear what happens with the older licences (as far as I can tell).

So, in a few months? Maybe. After the end of the year - if you already activated a windows 10 install? Also maybe. Now to the end of next july? Maybe.  After july? Naw, not happening.

I just imaged my systems, gave win10 a shot, and if I had issues, I could fall back to the old versions.

Comment: If Windows 10 is activated on the machine at least once before July 29 2016 you can download and install Windows 10 for the life of the machine.  If you don't activate Windows 10 on the machine before July 29th 2016 then you are required to purchase a license to Windows 10 in order to use it.  After November 2nd 2015 Windows 10 will activate with eligible Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1 license keys.  A license key becomes eligible provided the activation happens at least once before Juiy 29th 2016.

Comment: The reason I know so much about this is because I accepted the upgrade on July 29th so I have a vested interest to understand my rights provided to me by the license.  Your machine when upgraded to Windows 10 from a previous version is given a digital entitlement to Windows 10.  This digital entitlement is valid for your machine which is the reason you can go directly to Windows 10 without having to install the version of Windows the machine came with.